# How to echo the CODE (not the content) of a HTML-File in PHP?

Tags: php, html

As the title says. The following code does only show up the non-HTML-content and not the code of the snippet.html-file itself. So any idea/hint how this can be done? (Of course I'm new to PHP...)

```html
<!-- Lets say I have a snippet.html with the following code: -->

<a href="lorem">Lorem ipsum</a>


<!-- This code should be visible in another file via: -->

<pre><code>
  <?php echo html_entity_decode(file_get_contents('snippet.html')); ?>
</code></pre>


<!-- The result: Only non-HTML-content is visible: -->

Lorem ipsum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **encode** the HTML, not decode it.

```
<?php echo htmlentities(file_get_contents('snippet.html')); ?>
```

This will, for example, turn `<b>` into `&lt;b&lt;` so it will be shown as text in the browser instead of interpreted as markup.

Demo:

```html
&lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
```

Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php